# Synclock for creation of unique directories in multithreaded environment

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, parallel-processing, locking

In my application I am creating reports. The reports are created by jobs that run in parallel. The reports need to be stored in unique directories.

It is my understanding, that code in a `SyncLock` block can only be called by one thread at a time. So I came up with the following code for generating a unique path from the current date and time and a counter:

Edit: `DirectoryLock` is defined as `Private DirectoryLock As Object = New Object`

```vb
'Create a non existant path
Dim ID As String 'Unique ID, that is added to the path
Dim RandomReportName As String 'The resulting directory name
SyncLock DirectoryLock 'Lock the creation of the directory, to avoid the same names
    Dim number As Integer = 0
    Do
        number += 1
        ID = Format(number, "000") 'Create ID from a counter
        RandomReportName = "Report_" & Format(Date.Now, "yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss.fff") & "_(" & ID & ")" 'Generate the path
        opts.OutputPath = IO.Path.Combine(opts.OutputPath, RandomReportName)
    Loop Until IO.Directory.Exists(opts.OutputPath) = False 'Increase the counter, until a non existant path is found
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(opts.OutputPath) 'Create the directory in the synclock, so other threads will need to find a new name (higher counter)
End SyncLock 'Free the code
```

As far as I understood this, it should work. However when I run this with say 10 jobs in parallel at a time it happens often that multiple threads get the same pathname and I don't understand why.

What am I missing (as there must be something :-)) and how can such a problem be avoided?

Answers in both VB.NET or C# are very welcome.

Comment: Non-zero odds that "DirectoryLock" needs to be `Shared`.  We can't see from the snippet whether the threads each create a new object of the class that this code is a part of.  In which case DirectoryLock doesn't lock anything of course, every thread has its own copy of the member.  Do keep in mind that running this kind of code on more than one thread is very detrimental.  You only have one disk, it doesn't like to be commandeered around by multiple threads.  The end result can be a *lot* slower, dominated by the disk seek time overhead.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The report creation is only part of a whole process (receive job, evaluate data, create report, store results). The single tasks are executed one after another per job. But since the report creation is not the bottleneck it is helpful to run multiple jobs in parallel. I only have one `ReportCreator` class instance that is used by all jobs. I will try and create a simple example application to replicate the behaviour.

Comment: You could just use a `Guid` for the folder name and then no synchronisation would be required.

Comment: As a workaround I actually already did this. however this makes the names of course very bloated so I would like to avoid it. Thank you for the input however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching at the completely wrong end for an error.

I thought the lock was not working however the simple mistake was

```vb
opts.OutputPath = IO.Path.Combine(opts.OutputPath, RandomReportName)
```

I reuse the same variable for concatenation. So on further loop iterations the new RandomReportName is added to the already existing one.

The solution of course is to use a temporary variable

```vb
'Create a non existant path
Dim ID As String
Dim RandomReportName As String
Dim ResultPath As String = "" 'Stores the unique path name
SyncLock DirectoryLock
    Dim number As Integer = 0
    Do
        number += 1
        ID = Format(number, "000") 'Create ID from a counter
        RandomReportName = "Report_" & Format(Date.Now, "yyyy_MM_dd-HH_mm_ss.fff") & "_(" & ID & ")" 'Generate the path
        ResultPath = IO.Path.Combine(opts.OutputPath, RandomReportName) 'Assign the result path with the combined base path and unique name
    Loop Until IO.Directory.Exists(ResultPath) = False
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ResultPath)
    opts.OutputPath = ResultPath 'Store the temporary variable for further use
End SyncLock 'Free the code
```

Comment: Instead of trying to lock the entire path generation code code when all you want is a unique number, use Interlocked.Increment. Better yet, use a logging library that provides rolling files (almost all do).